# How to minimise $\mathbb{E}_X[\log(\text{sigmoid}(x + y))]$?

Tags: expected-value

I want to know whether I can obtain the closed form of the minimising value:

$$\text{argmin}_y \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p(x)}[\log(\text{sigmoid}(x + y))],$$

where the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is $\text{sigmoid}(x) = 1 / (1 + \exp{(-x)})$ and $p_X$ is the given probability density function.  Note that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.

Comment: Isn't the answer always $y=-\infty$?  (I'm ignoring your statement "$y$ is constant," because that renders the question nonsensical: you are asking which value of $y$ minimizes a function of $y.$)

Comment: @whuber I'm very sorry I tried to simplify the original problem to ask questions here, but in doing so I broke the structure of the problem at all. I'll update the question soon.

Comment: @T.Ogawa: Thanks for the additional information in the update.  However, I note from your update that you are now asking what is essentially a completely different problem.  Since your original posted question has already been answered, rather than giving this information as an update, it would be better to delete the update and then ask the question as a completely new question.

Comment: @T.Ogawa: Consistent with [advice on CV.meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2888/a-beautiful-answer-to-a-question-that-changed), I have edited to roll-back the update to remove your new question.  However, I would encourage you to post the updated information as a new question so that we can address this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the objective function as a [Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) you have:

$$H(y) = \int \limits_\mathscr{X} \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x-y)} dF(x).$$

Taking the first derivative with respect to $y$ gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\frac{dH}{dy}(y) 
&= \frac{d}{dy} \int \limits_\mathscr{X} \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x-y)} dF(x) \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x-y)} dF(x) \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} \frac{\exp(-x-y)}{(1 + \exp(-x-y))^2} dF(x) > 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

From this result we can see that the objective function is strictly increasing in $y$, so minimisation requires $y \rightarrow - \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral so I'll read the wikipedia. BTW, how about the original form of the problem in the updated question? Can I analyze in a similar way?

Comment: The only purpose of using the LS integral here is that you did not specify whether $X$ is continuous or discrete (or mixture).  LS integration allows you to write an expected value as an integral even if the random variable is discrete - that is really all it is used for in this context.

Comment: This might be deemed unnecessarily complex and confusing.  The sigmoid is increasing in y, no measure theory or calculus required

Comment: @dsaxton: Agree it's pretty simple.  I guess this is really just confirming that this monotonicity transfers over from the sigmoid function to its expectation.